# Laravel passing a parameter before model create

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do I pass a parameter to a Model before creating it, like so

```
$currency = Currency::forEntity($entity)->create([
    "name" => "Euro",
    "currency_code" => "EUR"
]);
```

How can I create a method that accepts for example the `$entity`, so that I can assign it in the `static::creating` method of that model by doing something like `$model->entity_id = ?` that passed entity ?

Currencies belong to `Entity`, so every currency will have an `entity_id`, currently this is achieved like so

```
static::creating( function ($model) {
    if (Auth::check() && is_null($model->entity_id)) {
        $model->entity_id = Auth::user()->entity->id;
    }
} );
```

I'm trying to pass the `entity_id` to the Model instead of relying on `Auth` guards or sessions to retrieve the currently logged-in user's entity all-together.

Comment: For what purpose and what is the relationship betwen `Currency` and `Entity`?

Comment: Currencies belong to Entity so every currency will have an entity_id, currently this is achieved like so
```
static::creating(
            function ($model) {
                if (Auth::check() && is_null($model->entity_id)) {
                    $model->entity_id = Auth::user()->entity->id;
                }
            }
        );
```

Im trying to pass the entity_id to the Model instead of relying on Auth guards or sessions to retrieve the currently logged in user's entity all-together.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious, but could you not just pass the `id` for the `entity` into the currencies `create` method as you're doing with the other values?